# Entity Framework Core 8 warning "Setting the sentinel value for the property to ensure the database default is used"

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have just upgraded to Entity Framework Core 8 from 7. Using code first, `Add-Migration` is now returning the following new warning:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
> The 'MyEnum' property 'MyEnumPropertyID' on entity type 'MyTableEntity' is configured with a database-generated default, but has no configured sentinel value. The database-generated default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'Error', since this is the CLR default for the 'MyEnum' type.
> Consider using a nullable type, using a nullable backing field, or setting the sentinel value for the property to ensure the database default is used when, and only when, appropriate. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-default-values for more information.

**Question**

1. What does this error mean? What is a sentinel value in SQL Server? (yes I followed the Microsoft link, but no info there)
2. How do I set a sentinel value for the enum property? (I don't want to use nullable)

**Code**

`MyTableEntity` is configured to use `MyEnum` as shown here:

```
public partial class MyTableEntity
{
    // primary key and other properties not shown

    // This is not a foreign key to another table, just an enum 
    public MyEnum MyEnumPropertyID { get; set; }   
}
```

The model builder defines the default as shown

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTableEntity>(entity =>
{
    //other properties not shown
    entity.Property(e => e.MyEnumPropertyID)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDefaultValue((object)MyEnum.Default)
        .HasConversion<int>(); //
}
```

And the enum is just a plain old garden variety enum

```
public enum MyEnum { Error, Default, HaveAGreatDay }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `default(MyEnum} == (MyEnum)0 == MyEnum.Error`. EF can't tell if you have explicitly assigned `MyEnum.Error`.

You can reserve a value in your enum that is invalid. Then inform EF to consider this value as an unassigned "[sentinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#database-defaults-for-enums)". eg `.HasSentinel(MyEnum.Unspecified)`. In which case the value will not be passed to the database, and the database default value will be used.

Or you store the property value in a `MyEnum?` [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#using-a-nullable-backing-field), then EF can tell the difference between unassigned and any explicit value.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. In my case I use the MyEnum.Error (whose int is 0) to indicate that the enum has not been set.  Does this mean I use .HasSentinal(MyEnum.Error)? But the sentinal then being used is the natural default of the enum (value=0).  This means the '0' will not be passed to the database, and the default (0) will be used? Sounds odd.  If I set my default to  .HasDefaultValue((object)MyEnum.Default) (not 0) and  .HasSentinal(MyEnum.Error) (0) then will this work?  Or must I now define a new MyEnum.Unspecified in the enum? Thanks for your help

Comment: Right, assuming you never want to insert an `.Error`. When EF detects this sentinal for new records, it will leave the column out of the `insert` sql statement. The database will then provide the column default, which should have been defined based on your `.HasDefaultValue((MyEnum)1)` when you create and apply migrations.

Comment: `.HasSentinal(default)` will result in exactly the same behaviour as previous versions, but now you need to be explicit to avoid the warning message when the database column default is not `default`.